# Javascript - Error ... is not a function inside a closure

Tags: javascript, object

In a for-loop commented as:

> // Iterate over the array and append each element as li

... there is a closure which works fine if I just put
console.log(tags[x]);
which would suggest that the closure works as intended. However, when I put the actual code that the closure should contain, ie. this.displayImg(tags[x]); it throws an error. When I click on li, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.displayImg is not a function
(anonymous function) @ script.js:49
```

Please advise how I can access this.displayImg from that place.

```
var myGallery = (function () {
    var s;

    return {
        settings: {
            data: JSON.parse(data),
            filter: document.getElementById("filter"),
            gallery: document.getElementById("gallery")
        },
        init: function () {
            // kick things off
            s = this.settings;
            // By default, call the fillImages function with 'all' tag
            this.createFilters("all");
        },
        createFilters: function (tag) {
            // Load the image data
            // I made imgs global as I couldn't access it from displayImg
            imgs = this.settings.data.images;

            // Get image tags and generate a tag array
            var tags = ["all"];

            for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(imgs).length; i++) {
                // Check if a tag is already in tags
                if (tags.indexOf(imgs[i].tag) > -1) {
                    // Yes, it is, so don't add it
                } else {
                    // No, it isn't, so add it to 'tags'
                    tags.push(imgs[i].tag);
                }
            }
            // Create an unordered list, assign a class to it and append to filter
            var ul = document.createElement('ul');
            ul.classList.add("ul-bare");
            this.settings.filter.appendChild(ul);

            // Iterate over the array and append each element as li
            for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
                var li = document.createElement('li');
                ul.appendChild(li);
                li.innerHTML = tags[i];
                li.onclick = (function (x) {
                    return function () {
                        console.log(tags[x]);
                        this.displayImg(tags[x]);
                    };
                })(i);
            }
        },
        displayImg: function (filter) {
            // Add images to #gallery
            for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(imgs).length; i++) {
                var div = document.createElement("img");
                // If the tage is 'all', display all images
                if (filter === "all") {
                    div.src = imgs[i].src;
                    this.settings.gallery.appendChild(div);
                } else {
                    // Display only images of certain category (tag argument)
                    if (imgs[i].tag === filter) {
                        div.src = imgs[i].src;
                        this.settings.gallery.appendChild(div);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
})();

myGallery.init();
```

Thank you

Comment: this inside handler referes to _li_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the `onclick`, `this` will be a reference to the DOM element that was clicked, not what `this` means where you're hooking it up.

If you want to access the object `this` refers to when you're setting up the handler, use a variable:

```
var thisObj = this;
for (...) {
```

...and then in the handler:

```
thisObj.displayImg(tags[x]);
```

Although in this case, since you don't need `this` to refer to the handler, you can make it a lot simpler with `Function#bind`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML = tags[i];
    li.onclick = function(x) {
        console.log(tags[x]);
        this.displayImg(tags[x]);
    }.bind(this, i);
}
```

`Function#bind` returns a new function that, when called, will call the original with a specific `this` value and any further arguments you give `bind` (followed by any arguments it receives at runtime).

---

Side note: You may as well just pass the tag in, rather than the index:

```
var thisObj = this;
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML = tags[i];
    li.onclick = (function(tag) {
        return function() {
            console.log(tag);
            thisObj.displayImg(tag);
        };
    })(tags[i]);
}
```

or

```
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML = tags[i];
    li.onclick = function(tag) {
        console.log(tag);
        this.displayImg(tag);
    }.bind(this, tags[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside handler `this` reference the DOM element. I would use bind which is also more readable solution for passing value of `i`:

```
li.onclick = function(x) {            
        console.log(tags[x]);
        this.displayImg(tags[x]);            
    }.bind(this, i);
```